# How to perform multiple operations on a list of user submitted variables in C++

Tags: c++, function, input

The program takes a few basic baseball statistics input by the user, and performs a few operations, ultimately outputting a complicated statistic. Although we only just started learning functions, I first tried doing this program with functions, failing miserably. I think the program can be performed without functions though, and here's my code so far:

(The posting system refuses to let me type anything after #include <, but I'm using iostream, iomanip, conio.h, and cmath.)

```
using namespace std;   

int main()   

{   
    int H, TB, BB, HBP, AB, YEAR, LGRS, LGPA;   
    double REqA, EqR, RA, WIN, AEqA, LGEqA, aWIN;   

    cout << "Enter the player's at bats." << endl;   
    cin >> AB;   

    cout << "Enter the player's hits." << endl;   
    cin >> H;   

    cout << "Enter the player's total bases." << endl;   
    cin >> TB;   

    cout << "Enter the player's walks." << endl;   
    cin >> BB;   

    cout << "Enter the player's times hit by pitch." << endl;   
    cin >> HBP;   

    cout << "Enter the year the player played." << endl;   
    cin >> YEAR;   

    if (YEAR != 2012)   
    {   
       cout << "Sorry, this program only supports the 2012 season." << endl;   
    }   

    else  

    {   
       LGRS = 21017;   
       LGPA = 184179;   
       LGEqA = 0.72401;   

    }      

    REqA = (H + TB + (1.5 * (BB + HBP))) / (AB + BB + HBP);   

    EqR = (2 * REqA / LGEqA - 1) * (AB + BB + HBP) * (LGRS / LGPA);   

    WIN = (EqR * EqR) / ((EqR * EqR) + (RA * RA));   

    aWIN = (WIN / (1 - WIN));   

    AEqA = pow(aWIN, 0.2) * 0.26;   

    cout << "The player had a " << AEqA << " EqA in " << YEAR << "." << endl;   

    getch();   

    return 0;   

}
```

The final output of AEqA is always 0, no matter what numbers are input at the start. If I set up the program to output REqA, the program is outputting the number it should. But I need to do all the steps coming after that for the final output of AEqA, and that always ends up as zero. I think the problem is with the line that calculates EqR, because if I set up the program to output EqR, the output is also always 0.

Comment: This should be pretty easy to debug: split up the equations over more lines and then place a breakpoint and step through and watch for the line that doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: TIP: Indent every line of code four spaces. This will allow your `#include` directives to appear correctly.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was told by the commenting system I had to indent every line four spaces to post my comment, but that information was provided after I posted the explanation in parentheses, and I guess I forgot to try again to post things after #include again.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better practice to use getline for your user input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  int H, TB, BB, HBP, AB, YEAR, LGRS, LGPA;   
  double REqA, EqR, RA, WIN, AEqA, LGEqA, aWIN; 

  cout << "Enter the player's at bats.? " << endl;
  getline (cin, AB);

  //etc ...

   return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why do you say that's better practice? Just curious, since this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 WIN = (EqR * EqR) / ((EqR * EqR) + (RA * RA));
```

your variable `RA` is never initialised. In such a case it is probably initialised to zero by default. In such a case, this would result in

```
WIN = 1
```

and so when you do this

```
aWIN = (WIN / (1 - WIN));
```

so you are doing a floating point division by zero which should result in infinity. I am not sure what calling `pow` on inifinity does but I am guessing it is not good. I have no idea what your variables represent but you will always get this problem when

```
RA = 0
```

so it would be a good idea to initialised it to something or catch the user input value. I would strongly suggest using a debugger to check that your variables are being correctly set/calculated as the program runs.

Note also that you are getting a zero here through integer division - you set

```
LGRS = 21017;   
LGPA = 184179;
```

and then on this line

```
EqR = (2 * REqA / LGEqA - 1) * (AB + BB + HBP) * (LGRS / LGPA);
```

the result of

```
(LGRS / LGPA)
```

ALWAYS equates to zero since `LGRS < LGPA`. The result of divisions of 2 integer types is unsurprisingly an integer and when the numerator and denominator are both positive, but the numerator is less than the denominator the result will be zero (research **integer division** on this site or the web in general). As a consequence, your product contains a zero term and hence `EqR == 0`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I still also get an output of 0 when outputting EqR, which is before RA. Any ideas about my error there?